# Tool to shrink exFAT filesystem offline for Linux

Tags: linux, exfat

As of 2021, is there a tool to shrink exFAT filesystem offline for Linux ?

I tested with `gparted` v1.3.1 but [gparted does not support exfat resizing](https://gparted.org/features.php).

Comment: Not that I know of. The information from https://superuser.com/questions/393132/shrink-exfat-partition seems to apply even today.

Answer (score 3):

It has nothing to do with gparted and everything with exfatprogs.

Please subscribe to https://github.com/exfatprogs/exfatprogs/issues/134